# Should I use me.invalidate or me.refresh when repainting my form?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, repaint

I'm experimenting on paint event in `Windows Form`, what I want to achieved is to repaint the colors of the arrow. I think I successfully did that, I just have a question on whether should I use the `Me.Invalidate` or `Me.Refresh` when performing the repaint event on the form? Both of them are working.

Note that I will create many objects later so one of my goals is to lessen the performance issues.

When you clicked the button 1 it will change the color of the `line 1` to yellow using the `Me.Invalidate`, when you clicked the button 2 it will change the `line 1` to blue using the `Me.Refresh`. Both of them are working.

This is my whole code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
        drawLeftArrow(e, "a", 100, 250, 400, 50)
    End Sub

    Dim aPen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Red, 8)
    Dim bPen As Pen
    Dim cPen As Pen

    Dim line1 As Point()
    Dim line2 As Point()
    Dim line3 As Point()

    Sub drawLeftArrow(e As PaintEventArgs, letterPosition As String, startPointX As Integer, startPointY As Integer, endPointX As Integer, endPointY As Integer)

        bPen = New Pen(Color.Green, 8)
        cPen = New Pen(Color.Yellow, 8)

        Dim mycap As Drawing2D.CustomLineCap = New Drawing2D.AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5)

        ' Create points that define curve.
        Dim startPoint As New Point(startPointX, startPointY)



        Dim endPoint As New Point(endPointX, endPointY)


        Select Case letterPosition
            Case "a"
                Dim middlePoint1 As New Point(startPointX + 250, startPointY)
                Dim middlePoint2 As New Point(startPointX + 300, endPointY + 150)
                line1 = {startPoint, middlePoint1}
                line2 = {middlePoint1, middlePoint2}
                line3 = {middlePoint2, endPoint}
                cPen.CustomEndCap = mycap
                ' Draw lines between original points to screen.
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(aPen, line1)
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(bPen, line2)
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(cPen, line3)
                Exit Select
        End Select

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        aPen = New Pen(Color.Yellow, 8)
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        aPen = New Pen(Color.Blue, 8)
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub
End class
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Intellisense tells you this sort of thing.  Invalidate: `Invalidates the specified region of the control (adds it to the control's update region, which is the area that will be repainted at the next paint operation), and causes a paint message to be sent to the control.` Whereas Refresh: `Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.`  There are Invalidate overloads which let you specify a region

Comment: Invalidate should be used.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed that one. So `refresh` means `all`? whereas `invalidates` can be used by `region`? Good point!